# Running a Python script in Node-RED results in [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, node-red

I am just starting out with Node-RED and trying to run a Python script but get the error "No such file or directory". Node-Red is running in docker on my Pi4.

```
python: can't open file '/home/pi/docker/nodered/data/python/bins.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In node red, I'm using an inject node to run an exec with the Python command then outputting to a debug node.

I can run the script from the command line using the same command so the path is correct. This is the output:

```
pi@raspberrypi4:/ $ python /home/pi/docker/nodered/data/python/bins.py
I am bloody here: /home/pi/docker/nodered/data/python/bins.py
```

So the path is correct. What am I doing wrong that's stopping Node Red seeing the script? I've read several posts that say to the use the full path. The only other thing I can think of is that docker can't see outside of itself so would require a relative path but I've tried this as well.

Feeling a bit dim at the moment!

Many thanks,

Comment: Have you mounted the file from the host machine into the container? Applications running in docker containers have no access to the host filesystem unless you explicitly bind mount files or directories into the container.

Comment: Hi, I haven't. I was naive enough to think that it being within the data directory would be sufficient.  I'll Google mounting. Thank you.

Comment: It will be, but you must use a path that is actually in the container, so `/data/bins.py`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is not correct, because it does not exist inside the container.

The point of containers is to isolate the application from the host machine (so it runs with a known set of dependent libraries and settings).

If you want to run the python file you will need to mount it into the container. e.g.

```
docker run -d -p 1880:1880 -v /home/pi/docker/nodered/data/python/bins.py:/data/bins.py nodered/node-red
```

You would then use the path `/data/bins.py` to point to the file in the exec  node.

If you have already mounted the `/home/pi/docker/nodered/data` into the container on `/data` then the same path would be used in the exec node without the need to the extra `-v /home/pi/docker/nodered/data/python/bins.py:/data/bins.py` to the command line.

```
docker run -d -p 1880:1880 -v /home/pi/docker/nodered/data:/data nodered/node-red
```

Path would be `/data/python/bins.py`

The important thing to know is what the path is INSIDE the container, not on the host.

Comment: Ah fab, thank you so much. I had /data mounted in my docker-compose.yml and now I've changed the path to /data/python/bins.py it is running. It's now giving me ModuleNotFound so I just need to work on importing all the modules I require into this container so off to Google I go again! One step forward. Really appreciate your time helping me out. Regards.

Comment: You will need to build your own container (by extending the standard container) to install the extra python modules into the container.